# mvc 3 System.AccessViolationException with vs 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate last week. We currently use VS 2010 Professional, so using the 2012 was my only easy option for testing.

I opened up VS 2012 Ultimate and opened a MVC 3 project that was written in VS 2010. and then undo checkout code. then doesn't run project and get the following error but similar projects work correctly.

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt. Source=WebDev.WebHost40
>   StackTrace: at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(Object
>   acceptedSocket) at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>   InnerException:

Comment: Was the visual studio 2012 opened with "Run As Administrator"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "then undo checkout code. then doesn't run project".  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Try to report this at Microsoft, this ain't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use IIS Express, visual studio development server is not a complete web server and it has lots of bug.

Comment: That's full of assumptions, why do you think he is using that and is this a known bug or are you just guessing?

Comment: I had faced many such similar problems, moved to IIS express and works better. There are known problems like unable to set custom http header error in mvc, caching controls don't work as expected.

Comment: Check stack trace, he is using internal development server.